# Proxy all requests on a port

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

I have a closed webservice in my network (a thermostat), which can be access on 192.168.0.1 port 80.

Now I want to access that thermostat from the internet but I don't want to just forward that port because there is no security on it, don't want anyone even have the chance of screwing around with the heat :)

I have a raspberry PI running permanently and I forwarded port 25 to the PI.

Now I want the incoming request on port 85 to be authenticated and forwarded to the local network 192.168.0.1 port 80 and the response be sent back to the original request again.

I was thinking of writing a small webservice in python which does the requests, but first I wanted to check if somebody would know an easy out of the box installable solution.

Should I be looking for a proxy? Or would another piece of software be perfect for this?

Comment: well, I'd say use iptables to forward the packets, but the authentication part is the tricky bit. How did you plan to authenticate them, assuming you aren't writing any custom code? http://www.fclose.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/

Comment: You can use `apache` with `mod_proxy` enabled to forward incoming requests to your device, and use the regular apache access rules to authenticate the requests. Alternatives could include `nginx`.

Comment: I have the same problem with my domotics: I can remotely turn lights on or off, check cameras, turn heating on or off, and so on. I thought is much simpler to setup a routed OpenVPN, allow only LAN access to the home automation portal. Quick, safe, proven.

Comment: The OpenVPN part is actually not a bad idea, I could setup a simple VPN on the RPi which the remote server connects to.